# How to finish all activity when move to other modul via sidemenu

Tags: android, android-activity, side-menu

I will explain my problem:

I have 4 main menus can access from Dashboard page such as :

- Menu A
- Menu B
- Menu C
- Menu D

Inside each menu there are sub menu , so the tree of menus will look like (ALL Menu is an independent Activity):

- Menu A -> SubA-1 -> SubA-2
- Menu B -> SubB-1 -> SubB-2
- Menu C -> SubC-1 -> SubC-2
- Menu D -> SubD-1 -> SubD-2

When i access menu A to SubA-1 and then SubA-2. So now i inside SubA-2.
I move to Menu B from SubA-2.

From Menu B i access SubB-1. So Now i inside SubB-1. When i pressed back button i will move sequence like this :
SubB-1 -> Menu B -> SubA-2 -> SubA-1 -> Menu A

How to avoid Menu A Activity still called when pressed back button (but don't give suggest to block the back button)? I use this but not working perfectly :

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

If you need more information about case you can put in the comment below.

> **UPDATED :**
>
> User not allowed back to menuA if they come from MenuB. But They still
>   alowed back to Menu A if they come from subA-1 (sub menu of menu A).

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried overriding [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())

Comment: I already try onBackPressed() and working (i call new Dashboard activity using intent). Is it good way? that i know instance new activity cost is expensive. Am i wrong?

Comment: @Patrick yes it is okay, do that and clear backstack when going back to dashboard, I suggest to use fragment for the sub menu and the dashboard will be the activity only. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this it **requires API level >= 11.**

```
Intent i = new Intent(OldActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: How about DashBoard Page ? will it close too? Cause i want my Dashboard still active.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to **A -> SubA-1** you have to set flag like this

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

So it will not add your activity in your stack .

When you are going to **SubA-2 -> B** you have to set flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

And in your B activity `onbackpress` set simple intent to Dashboard activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: How about DashBoard Page ? will it close too? Cause i want my Dashboard still active.

Comment: No it will not effect on your deshboard as long as you don't open it form other activity.

Comment: How about if i press back from SUbA-1 ? Will i go to Menu A?

Comment: No it will goto Dashboard activity because we clear that menuA from stack.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it happens is because the Android `Activity` has a default function wherein when you intent and not specify the type of intent, it will be by default put the activity in the backstack. In order to avoid that you just simply clear the backstack except the First one on `startActivity` like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

But what I think when you are doing a submenu type application, it is best to use fragment rather than activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    finishAffinity();
    return;
}
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can finish the Menu A activity that you don't want the users to go back to. For instance, in your Menu A activity, right after you call startActivity, call finish(). When the users hit the back button, they will not be able to go to the Menu A activity because it has been killed off the stack.

Comment: Not really like that. I'm not problem if user back to Menu A if the user do back in SubA-1. That not allowed if they move from menu B to Menu A or to Sub Menu of A.